# If in if condition string is given it is treated as true but what it return?

Tags: c, if-statement

Why exactly is a string literal in an if-condition treated as true?

```
if("whatiamreturning")
//this is true. I want to know y?
```

Based on the above, what happens here?

```
#‎include‬<stdio.h>
void main() {
    static int i;
    for(;;) { //infinite loop
        if(i+++"The Matrix")
            // what is happening in the above line?
            printf("Memento");
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Find who wrote this: `i+++"The Matrix"` and take away their coding license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if("whatiamreturning")
```

is equivalent to

```
if (1)
```

This is because `"whatiamreturning"` is a `char []` that decays into a non-NULL `char const*` inside the `if()`. Any non-NULL pointer evaluates to `true` in the context of a boolean expression.

The line

```
if(i+++"The Matrix")
```

can be simplified to:

```
if( (i++) + "The Matrix")
```

In the first iteration of the loop, the value of `i` is `0`. Hence, the `(i++) + "The Matrix"` evaluates to `"The Matrix"`.

In the second iteration of the loop, the value of `i` is `1`. Hence, the `(i++) + "The Matrix"` evaluates to `"he Matrix"`.

However, the loop never ends and goes into the territory of undefined behavior since `(i++) + "The Matrix"` never evaluates to `0` and the value of `i` keeps on increasing.

Perhaps they meant to use:

```
  if(i++["The Matrix"])
```

which will allow the expression inside `if()` it to be `0` after `10` iterations.

**Update**

If you are following somebody else's code, stay away anything else that they have written. The `main` function can be cleaned up to:

```
int main() {
    char name[] = "The Matrix";
    int i = 0;
    for( ; name[i] != '\0'; ++i )
    {
        printf("Memento\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `"..."` is not a `char*`. It is of type `char[some number]`. Array decay happens and you have a pointer.

Comment: @Deduplicator, indeed. Thanks for letting me know. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

It will return the address of first element of the string `whatiamreturning`.
Basically when you assign a string literal to a `char` pointer

```
char *p;
p = "whatiamreturning";
```

the assignment doesn't copy the the characters in `whatiamreturning`, instead it makes `p` point to the first character of the string and that's why string literals can be sub-scripted

```
char ch = "whatiamreturning"[1];
```

`ch` will will have character `h` now. This worked because compiler treated `whatiamreturning` as a `char *` and calculated the base address of the literal.

---

`if(i+++"The Matrix")` is equivalent to

```
if( i++ + "The Matrix")
```

or it can be rewritten as

```
if(&("The Matrix"[i++]))
```

which will be `true` for every `i` and results in an infinite loop. Ultimately, the code will suffer from **undefined behavior** due to integer overflow for variable `i`.

Comment: Actually it would output `"Memento"` 11 times and then cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Matt: Which poinsons the entire execution and means the program has ***no defined behavior at all***.

Comment: @haccks: The first UB is far earlier than the signed integer overflow, even ignoring the function signature...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>    if(i+++"The Matrix") // what is happening here please help here to understand
> ```

This will take the value of `i`, add the pointer value of the location of the string `"The Matrix"` in memory and compare it to zero. After that it will increase the value of `i` by one.

It's not very useful, since the pointer value could be basically any random number (it depends on architecture, OS, etc). And thus the whole program amounts to printing `Memento` a random number of times (likely the same number each run though).

Perhaps you meant to write `if(*(i+++"The Matrix"))`. That would loop 10 times until it `i+"The Matrix"` evaluates to the address pointing to the `NUL` byte at the end of the string, and `*(i+"The Matrix")` will thus return `0`.

Btw, spaces are a nice way to make your code more readable.

Comment: Not print arbitrary number of times, but UB!!

Comment: I'm not sure this is UB. The pointer isn't dereferenced. I guess if `i` needs to wrap around then that would be UB though, so it could be.

Comment: Creating a pointer with pointer arithmetic to anywhere but inside the object your pointer started in resp. to the end of it is undefined behavior. No dereferencing neccessary. The signed integer overflow which would otherwise happen causes UB too otherwise, sure.

Comment: You're probably right. I'm too tired to look it up right now anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Why exactly is a string literal in an if-condition treated as true?
>
> ```
> if("whatiamreturning")
> ```

The string literal `"whatiamreturning"` is a constant of type `char[]`.
In nearly all contexts, including this one, arrays decay to pointers to their first element.
In a boolean context, like the condition of an `if`-statement, all non-zero values are true.
As the pointer points to an object, it is not the null-pointer, and thus is true.

> Based on the above, what happens here?
>
> ```
> #‎include‬<stdio.h>
> void main() {
> ```

The above is your first instance of **Undefined Behavior**, whatever happens, it is right.
We will now pretend the error is corrected by substituting `int` for `void`.

Now, your loop:

```
    static int i;
```

Static variables are default initialized, so `i` starts with value 0.

```
    for(;;) { //infinite loop
        if(i+++"The Matrix")
            // what is happening in the above line?
            printf("Memento");
        else
            break;
    }
```

This loop has **Undefined Behavior** as well.

The condition takes `i` and adds it to the string literal `"Memento"` which decayed to a pointer like in the previous example, interpreting the resultant pointer in a boolean context, and as a side-effect incrementing `i`.
As long as `i` is no more than `strlen("The Matrix")+1` on entry, everything is ok, the pointer points to an element of the string literal or one past, and the standard guarantees that's not a null pointer.
The moment it is though, all hell breaks loose because calculating such a pointer is **Undefined Behavior**.

Well, now that we know the loop is UB, let's ignore the loop too.
The rest of the program is:

```
}
```

Which is ok, because even though `main` has a return type of `int`, there's a special rule which states that if control reaches the end of `main` without executing a `return`-statement, an implicit `return 0;` is added.

Side-note: If an execution of a program encounters Undefined Behavior anywhere, the whole program is undefined, not only from that point on:
[Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/27/10537746.aspx)